# get the title of a YouTube video

Tags: php, youtube-api

I am using following code to get title of some YouTube video, which was working fine previously but I am getting some error/warnings since last few days,

```
$entry = simplexml_load_file('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/' . $key);
return ($entry) ? ucwords(strtolower($entry->children('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/')->group->title)) : false;
```

> Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/jIP4xI9C8us:1: parser error : Document is empty in /home/public_html/panel/index.php on line 214
>
> Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: in /home/public_html/panel/index.php on line 214
>
> Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: ^ in /home/public_html/panel/index.php on line 214
>
> Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/jIP4xI9C8us:1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in /home/public_html/panel/index.php on line 214
>
> Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: in /home/public_html/panel/index.php on line 214
>
> Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: ^ in /home/public_html/panel/index.php on line 214

Comment: `Parser error : Document is empty`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's my way.

use Youtube Data API v3.0

```
$searchResponse = $youtube->videos->listVideos('id','snippet,statistics',
        array('id' => 'CSV_VIDEO_IDS_HERE',
              'fields' => 'items(id,snippet(title,publishedAt,channelId,channelTitle,thumbnails(default),description),statistics)'
    ));

foreach($searchResponse["items"] as $item)
{
    echo "video titles: ".$item['snippet']['title'];
}
```

[google-api-php-client library](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try replacing your call to `simplexml_load_file` with the following function and see if it has the same issue? Sounds like your host may have changed some PHP security settings.

```
function load_youtube_xml($url) {
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.YourWebSiteName.com/');
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $response;
}
$xml = load_youtube_xml(YOUTUBE_URL);
```

P.S. When I remove `:1` from your URL, it loads the file up when going there in a browser.

Comment: Patrick, Thanks for your response I just replaced the code with existing now when I try to get title its redirecting youtube on same video.

Answer (score 0):

My way:

function

```
function getVideoInfo($videoID){
    if($videoID == ""){
        return false;   
    }
    /* Get the xml file from YouTube Data API */
    $books = simplexml_load_file('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/'.$videoID);
    $user = $books->author[0]->name;
    $desc = $books->content[0]; 
    $title = $books->title[0];
    $link = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v='.$videoID;

    return array($user, $title, $desc, $link); 
}
```

main

```
$info = getVideoInfo($YourVideoID);
    echo $info[0];  //username
    echo '<br />';
    echo $info[1];  //title
    echo '<br />';
    echo $info[2];  //description
    echo '<br />';
    echo $info[3];  //link
```